# How to show a button half on one layout and half on another layout in android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to design a layout like the image below:

[image]

I tried to do it using Relative layout but I did not come up with a solution. It should be in the same position for all device screen. How can I achieve it???
I tried this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/obaz" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout_top"
        android:background="@drawable/obaz2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_atoz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"

            android:background="@drawable/button_active" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using a parent framelayout with 2 child views 1. your main relative layout ( having 2 children top & bottom) 2. The middle button with gravity center_vertical and any other alignment you want

Comment: May be it is correct answer but the problem is, it is not responsive. That means if I change the device from hdpi to xdpi, it cannot works.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the `Button` declaration outside of your `RelativeLayout` relative_layout_bottom
and then place it where you like.

For example:
Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/obaz" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_atoz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_active" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout_top"
        android:background="@drawable/obaz2" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But I have two relative layout. One is on top and another one is on bottom. And I want to show it between two relative layout. You did not understand my question may be.

Comment: You use a main RelativeLayout. In this layout, you have two RelativeLayouts and a Button. in that case, you don't need to put the Button inside the "third" RelativeLayout.