# How to show a button over between two layout connection point?

Tags: android, layout

I asked same question and the question link is : [How to show a button half on one layout and half on another layout in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091362/how-to-show-a-button-half-on-one-layout-and-half-on-another-layout-in-android)
I did not find any solution for this problem. I want to make this layout responsive for all device. Anyone can help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: But asking second time I got a solution for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..!Let me know if it helps.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#d67070">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#70a7d6">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout_top"
         >
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_atoz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Sharifur Rahman i m glad to help.